# list on the authorized Google user `accounts` resource in Analytics API

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have the following code returning the Google Analytics `Accounts` which have my app's client email authorized under `User Management` section in Google Analytics `Admin` view. However, I need it to return the accounts that belong to the authorized user instead, so that he can choose one he'd like to query.

```
$service = new \Google_Service_Analytics($this->client);
$management_accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
```

`$this->client` is the Google API client, and has already asked user `myuser@email.com` if this application can "View and Analyze" his data and everything has been authenticated. I can query the API successfully so authentication is not issue. I just need above functionality and cannot locate within docs

Comment: Why not just display a dropdown to the user so they can select the one they are interested?   This isn't functionality in the Google Analytics API this is basic PHP coding you are going to have to do here.

Comment: Well, that is the plan, however the API has changed in v2. When reverting back to v1, I get the expected results from the above API call. I even opened an [issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/747) for it as it is a very strange behavior to change from v1 to v2

Comment: This isn't an issue with the php client library.  This is an issue with your understanding of Oauth2.   All calls are against the current authenticated user.

Comment: Here is a link to the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list) as well as the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAccountGuide). In your issue you state the "results are not right" in what way are they not right? are you using a service account?